# Capture response body when urllib2.urlopen throws exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am issuing a GET, and I am receiving a 503 code.

From Network tab of Chrome debugger, I see the code and the response (which is what I am after).

However, when making this call via Python, a HTTPError is thrown, I see the error code, but I don't see a response.

How can I capture the response that I am getting through the browser?

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'})
r = urllib2.urlopen(request,timeout=30)
```

Comment: can you provide the url?

Comment: it's an internal service
internalservice:12345/healthcheck

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for urllib2.HTTPError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError) says:

> Though being an exception (a subclass of URLError), an HTTPError can also function as a non-exceptional file-like return value (the same thing that urlopen() returns).

That is, if you catch the `HTTPError`, you can call `.read()` on it.

```py
request = urllib2.Request(url, ...)
try:
  r = urllib2.urlopen(request,timeout=30)
except urllib2.HTTPError as he:
  print(he.reason)
  print(he.read())
  raise
```

As an aside,

- you should stop using end-of-life Python 2.7 and shift to Python 3
- The [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) makes handling HTTP with all its quirks and features much nicer.